# How do I overcome the auto-number row when trying to add a column to a Microsoft access table through Java?

Tags: java, database, ms-access

For a project, I have GameNPCID as an auto-number in Access. I can't figure out how to add a set of values to the table, while letting the auto-number primary key handle itself. The primary key in this is called GameNPCID and there are two foreign keys: GameID and NPCID.

String sql = "INSERT INTO GameNPCLink ( NPCFirstName, NPCMood, GameID, NPCID, NPCAge, Life) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

```
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        preparedStatement.setString(1, nPCfirstName);
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, nPCMood);
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, GameID);
        preparedStatement.setInt(4, nPCID);
        preparedStatement.setInt(5, nPCAge);
        preparedStatement.setInt(6, life);
```

Obviously, this is not the way to do it, but if anyone could lend me a hand that would be great.

I have tried various ways of changing numbers and variables but implementing access in java is quite new to me and I can't seem to find any tutorials online. (Also, if someone knows good tutorials, that would be helpful)

Comment: Perhaps use the **[ALTER TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/alter-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql)** SQL statement. Should work with **UCanAccess 4+** JDBC-driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude `GameNPCID` from the field list and also one parameter (question mark).

Then pass the remaining field values as you do, though adjust the index of these.

Comment: I have tried this but I am now getting an error saying foreign key no parent; GAMENPCLINK_NPCGAMENPCLINK table: GAMENPCLINK value: 1. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Study the database scheme to find out the primary and the foreign table of that reference.